# Expression in C++

Tags: c++, expression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FAQ : Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/faq-undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

In C++ there are expressions which look very ugly and bizarre. I was going through an article on a local community and found this expression `i = (i, ++i,i) + i;` there. Is it expression fine or does it have some kind of problem? `i` is of a primitive type.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/faq-undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points. In this case, the final `i` in the expression, the one on the rhs of the `+`, is not sequenced relative to the `++i` in the middle.

Comment: Almost every day the same question...

Comment: Steve Jessop What do you mean by not sequenced. Can you be a bit more precise?

Comment: @Armen: to be somewhat fair to the questioners, sometimes the expression actually is UB, sometimes it isn't. To be less fair to the questioners: read a book.

Comment: @Brendan: if there's anything in that C++-FAQ question/answers which you don't understand, please ask specific questions about it.

Comment: Steve Jessop OK there is already something related here. OK reading it.

Comment: @Brendan: thanks, appreciated. The problem is that nobody is born understanding sequence points, the standard isn't crystal clear, and apparently they're very badly taught/learned. So the people who answer C and C++ questions on SO get this one a lot.